Is it safe to access MetaMask secrets from saved files in IndexedDB?
From what I’ve learned, MetaMask stores its secrets (mnemonic seed phrase and private keys) in IndexedDB, and this data is encrypted with the password set during wallet creation.
I’m considering inspecting those stored files in my system to understand how the secrets are managed and stored. But before proceeding, I have some concerns:
1- Is it safe to access these saved files directly?
Could merely attempting to access or read the files pose any security risks to my wallet?
2- If the data is encrypted, is there any harm in manually inspecting the files, provided I do not alter them?
3- What precautions should I take when accessing these files to ensure that I don’t compromise the wallet’s integrity or accidentally expose sensitive information?

It should be safe if MetaMask isn't running. If you backed up the mnemonic it shouldn't matter even if the wallet files are destroyed.
In any case I'd recommend to create a new wallet for testing, in a separate browser profile, or using a VM.
